# Why does my RunWorkerCompleted not receive the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, .net-4.5

I can see from my debug messages that e.Result equals to "Success" all the way through the DoWorker method, but at the beginning of the RunWorkerCompleted method e.Result returns nothing at all.

This is the __construct for the WinForm

```
public LicenseValidator()
{
    // Initialize the UI
    InitializeComponent();

    // Start the background worker
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    // Tell debug log that the UI thread is still processing
    Debug.WriteLine("UI thread running");  
}
```

And here is my worker_DoWork method

```
public async void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Tell debug log that the worker thread is now running
    Debug.WriteLine("Worker thread running");

    // Define variables
    String HWID = Security.FingerPrint.Value();
    String APIPath = "http://xxxxxxxxx.net/api.php";
    String Serial;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    String responseString;

    // Check for license in AppData
    try{
        // Get license path
        String licensePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + @"\UniLeech\License.txt";
        // License exists, validate it
        if (File.Exists(licensePath))
        {
            Serial = File.ReadAllText(licensePath);
            Debug.WriteLine(Serial);
            response = await client.GetAsync(APIPath + "?hwid=" + HWID + "&serial=" + Serial);
            responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
            dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            if (jObj.success == "true")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("License validation was successful");
                e.Result = "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Result = jObj.error;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Result);
        }
        // License does not exist, prompt for one
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("License file not found");
            e.Result = "Unregistered";
        }
    }
```

Finally my worker_RunWorkerCompleted method

```
public void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Worker completed");
    String result = e.Result as String;
    if ((e.Error == null))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("No errors");
        Debug.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Worker cancelled");
        }
        switch ((String)e.Result.ToString())
        {
            case "Success":
                this.Hide();
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                Main mainForm = new Main();
                mainForm.Show();
                break;

            case "Banned":
                popupError("ERROR: License revoked!",
                           "Your license has been revoked, contact Time Sheep for more information. You can purchase a new one by visiting the ordinary order link."
                          );
                break;

            case "Invalid":
                popupError("ERROR: Invalid serial/HWID",
                           "Either your serial number or hardware identifier was invalid. If you purchased UniLeech, please contact Time Sheep with proof of purchase."
                          );
                break;

            case "Unregistered":
                this.Hide();
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                Register registerForm = new Register();
                registerForm.Show();
                break;

            default:
                MessageBox.Show((string)e.Result, "ERROR");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

On execution the following debug messages appear (Case: I have the file and e.Result should be "Success"):

```
UI thread running
Worker thread running
0123-1234-1234 (The value of Serial)
Worker completed
No errors
{"success": "true","action": "validate","error": "None"} (Returned from web API)
License validation was successful
Success
RunWorkerCompleted finished
```

I suspect the issue is caused by the DoWork method being asynchronous, but I don't know how to use HttpClient synchronously.

Comment: Casting the result of calling `ToString()` to `string` seems a bit over the top...

Comment: I suggest you change this: `Debug.WriteLine(result);` to `Debug.WriteLine("Result = " + result);` - that will make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: @Jon Oh, did I forget to remove that?.. Yes, you're right, but this is my first ever C# program, and coming with only PHP experience is difficult, thinking of how complicated PHP is with it's conversion matrix and such.

Comment: And changing it returns `Result = `

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use `await` inside of a background worker.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Well, you *can* as the OP is demonstrating, it just doesn't work as intended and really *shouldn't* be done.

Comment: @RichardSchneider What's best practice to send the GET request in a synchronous manner then?

Comment: Okay, I just added .Result to the 2 async requests and removed the async keyword from the method, that helped, but I still want to know why tasks are better than backgroundworkers, because backgroundworkers are far easier to read and understand (In my holy opinion)

Comment: @TimeSheep Because you're creating a new thread just so it can do nothing 99.99% of the time, as opposed to just not creating a new thread at all and letting the computer do nothing for the 99.99% of the time nothing needs to be happening.

Comment: @TimeSheep: BGW code is always more complex than `Task.Run`. And as @Servy points out, for I/O, `async` is more efficient than BGW.

Comment: @StephenCleary the problem is the perspective from which I look at this. At first glance, for simple things such as this, it seems simple to understand, although it might not be very effective in the end. Look at it as my entry point to multi-threading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an `async` `DoWork`. `BackgroundWorker` assumes that when `DoWork` returns, it is completed.

You don't need `BackgroundWorker` at all. Just use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: If he does this he'll want to change `File.ReadAllText` to use async file IO.  After that he doesn't even need `Task.Run`, he can just call it all directly from the UI thread as it won't be blocking.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to using BGW rather than tasks? I feel I understand the BGW better, I've been so lost in tasks.

Comment: @Servy: Good point; he could just make the whole thing `async`. @TimeSheep: BGW is still available, but `Task`-based programming is better. The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) are quite good and [I have an intro as well](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). BGW isn't *deprecated*, but `async` can do everything BGW can do with shorter, more maintainable code and fewer pitfalls (e.g., the nesting problem I describe in my [`SynchronizationContext` article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)).

Comment: @TimeSheep The BGW is good when you have long running *CPU Bound* code.  It is *not* effective when you have long running IO bound code, and as such it would make your code much less effective to use a BGW, as you'd need to use entirely blocking IO methods (or block the async methods).  Using an entirely non-BGW solution you can avoid blocking a thread entirely.  In short, this particular use case doesn't fit into the model BGW is designed to work in; trying to force it is...not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I will definitely look into it, but seeing how insignificant this program is, I'm not going to redo it to utilize tasks. I prefer starting out with the things I partially understand, i.e. BGW. This is only a project I've set up for myself to get into the language :)